# How to rearrange text file via awk?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I wanna print field (from 4th to the last field) as new line for each by inserting increasing arithmetically variable (from 5 to 25) after 3rd field in the text file.

Data format:

```
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 1.2 2.5 3 4.8 5.2
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 2.3 7.5 8.7 8.7 10
```

.

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=25;i+=5) print $1,$2,$3,i,$(3+i/5)}'
```

Desired output:

```
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 5 1.2
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 10 2.5
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 15 3
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 20 4.8
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 25 5.2
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 5 2.3
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 10 7.5
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 15 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 20 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 25 10
```

Desired output 2:

```
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 5 5.2
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 10 4.8
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 15 3
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 20 2.5
01.01.1995 01.00 1.0 25 1.2
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 5 10
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 10 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 15 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 20 7.5
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 25 2.3
```

So the first three field should be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few obvious ways to do the arithmetic - for example

```
$ awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,5*(i-3),$i}' file
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 5 1.2
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 10 2.5
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 15 3
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 20 4.8
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 25 5.2
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 5 2.3
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 10 7.5
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 15 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 20 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 25 10
```

or

```
$ awk '{for(i=5;i<=25;i+=5) print $1,$2,$3,i,$(3+i/5)}' file
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 5 1.2
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 10 2.5
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 15 3
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 20 4.8
01.01.1995 01:00 1.0 25 5.2
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 5 2.3
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 10 7.5
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 15 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 20 8.7
31.01.1995 23.00 31.0 25 10
```

To reverse the order of the final field, start at `NF` and count down e.g.

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=25;i+=5) print $1,$2,$3,i,$(NF+1-i/5)}'
```

Comment: So NF is a built-in variable that contains number of fields in the current record. Here, $NF gives last field in my view. I don't understand $i. I mean for any i variable $i =$5?

Comment: @chess_freak `$i` returns the value of the `i`th field so `$4`, `$5` ... `$NF` as `i` is incremented in the loop

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was tried code like `awk 'BEGIN {for(i=5;i<=25; i+=5) print $1,$2,$3,i,$i}' file`.

Comment: @chess_freak a `BEGIN` block is executed before any lines of `file` are processed (hence `$1`,`$2` and so on will be empty)

Comment: I tried different way and again result was wrong. `awk '{for(i=5;i<=25; i+=5) print $1,$2,$3,i,$i}' file`. I think I have to use NF.

Comment: @chess_freak please see edit for how to do the arithmetic in that case

Comment: what if I change desired output for the last field like `5.2, 4.8, 3, 2.5, 1.2` instead of `1.2, 2.5,  3, 4.8, 5.2`.

Comment: @chess_freak you can print the arguments in any order you wish `print $(3+i/5),i,$3,$2,$1` or whatever

Comment: check my question, please. I edited it. I mean it is like in reverse order for desired output 2.

Comment: @chess_freak added to my answer - really this is just about arithmetic now rather than Ubuntu

Comment: shouldn't code be `awk '{for(i=5;i<=25;i+=5) print $1,$2,$3,i,$(NF+5-i/5)}'`